# Bibliography style for multiple authors

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want capital letters if there are more than 3 authors with a + at the end. I use Overleaf.

Bibliography setup:

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  maxbibnames=10,
]{biblatex}
\title{A bibLaTeX example}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

Bib file:

```
@book{myBook,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin and John Doe",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "myBook"
}
```

**Outcome:**

[Goo+93]  Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, Alexander Samarin, and TimTester.The LATEX Companion. Reading, Massachusetts: Addison-Wesley, 1993.

**Prefered Outcome:**

[GMS+93]  Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, Alexander Samarin, and TimTester.The LATEX Companion. Reading, Massachusetts: Addison-Wesley, 1993.

**Difference:**
[Goo+93] vs. [GMS+93]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What's the difference between to Outcome and the Prefered Outcome?

Comment: [Goo+93] vs. [GMS+93]

Comment: Since it is uncommon to state the answer to the question in the question itself, I rolled back your edit. You can indicate the answer you went with by accepting the answer below. (But editing answers into questions can be confusing and in case of multiple answers may defeat the voting system.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `minalphanames=3`.

`biblatex` will use `minalphanames` many names from the list if it is longer than `maxalphanames`. The default value for `maxalphanames` is `3` and for `minalphanames` it is `1`. That means that a list of more than three authors is shortened to one author plus "et al."/"+". With `minalphanames=3,` such a list is shortened to three authors plus "et al."/"+".

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  maxbibnames=10,
  minalphanames=3,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{myBook,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach
                 and Alexander Samarin and John Doe},
    title     = {The \LaTeX\ Companion},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts},
    keywords  = {myBook}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{myBook,sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [GMS+93] Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, Alexander Samarin and John Doe. The LaTeX Companion. Reading, Massachusetts: Addison-Wesley, 1993. [SR98] Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. [Wor02] Nancy Worman. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002.]